# Error CreatImage()-opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I'm getting this error

`imageResized=cv.CreateImage((64,64),8, 1) NameError: name 'cv' is not defined`

Here is my code:

```
import numpy
import cv2


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True): 
retval, frame = cap.read() 
cv2.imshow("frame",frame) cv2.waitKey(10) 
a = (200,80)#(x,y) 
b = (450,400)#(x,y) 
cv2.rectangle(frame,a, b, (0,255,0),3) 
crop_frame=frame[80:400,200:450] #y,x

cv2.imwrite("face.jpg", frame)

frame=cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)   
imageResized=cv.CreateImage((64,64),8, 1)
cv.Resize(cv.fromarray(frame), imageResized)
vector = numpy.asarray(frame)
print vector
```

I've changed to `cv2.CreateImage` and get this: `"AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CreateImage'"`

Can you guys help me? thanks

Comment: there is a misspelling in your code. You used `cv` instead of `cv2`.

Comment: @Constantine, it's not misspelled, it's just the  *older* api, which should no more be used.

Comment: @berak! Yeah But according to the code he imported `cv2` so he has to use `cv2` instead of `cv`! so another way is to use `import cv` instead of `import cv2`

Answer (score 1):

You can do either one of the following:

```
>>> import cv
>>> cv.CreateImage
<built-in function CreateImage>
```

or

```
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.cv.CreateImage
<built-in function CreateImage>
```

Comment: If you are going to post a one line answer, please add some extra information to make sure that the OP knows what the problem is (e.g. not resolving the methods properly).